# StackOverflowError during class transformation on startup of Liberty Server

Tags: hibernate, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

My OpenLiberty-Server throws a StackOverflowError on startup.
I'm using OpenLiberty 23.0.0.12 and Hibernate 6.4.2.Final.

The error detail is:

```
E CWWJP0055E: An error occurred while attempting to transform the org.hibernate.jpa.internal.enhance.EnhancingClassTransformerImpl$Entry Java Class.  The following failure detail was gathered: 
----------
Exception thrown by transformer:
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.base/java.io.InputStream.<init>(InputStream.java:61)
    at com.ibm.ws.artifact.zip.internal.ZipFileEntry$1.<init>(ZipFileEntry.java:199)
    at com.ibm.ws.artifact.zip.internal.ZipFileEntry.getInputStream(ZipFileEntry.java:199)
    at com.ibm.ws.artifact.overlay.internal.DirectoryBasedOverlayContainerImpl$OverlayDelegatingEntry.getInputStream(DirectoryBasedOverlayContainerImpl.java:488)
    at com.ibm.ws.adaptable.module.internal.AdaptableEntryImpl.adapt(AdaptableEntryImpl.java:104)
    at com.ibm.ws.adaptable.module.internal.InterpretedEntryImpl.adapt(InterpretedEntryImpl.java:68)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.ContainerClassLoader$EntryUniversalResource.getActualBytes(ContainerClassLoader.java:373)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.ContainerClassLoader$EntryUniversalResource.getByteResourceInformation(ContainerClassLoader.java:365)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.ContainerClassLoader$SmartClassPathImpl.getByteResourceInformation(ContainerClassLoader.java:1226)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.ContainerClassLoader.findClassBytes(ContainerClassLoader.java:1628)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findClassBytes(AppClassLoader.java:540)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findClass(AppClassLoader.java:324)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findOrDelegateLoadClass(AppClassLoader.java:714)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.loadClass(AppClassLoader.java:586)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.loadClass(AppClassLoader.java:553)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.enhance.EnhancingClassTransformerImpl.getEnhancer(EnhancingClassTransformerImpl.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.enhance.EnhancingClassTransformerImpl.transform(EnhancingClassTransformerImpl.java:49)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAPUnitInfo.transformClass(JPAPUnitInfo.java:1263)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.ClassLoadingServiceImpl$ClassFileTransformerAdapter.transform(ClassLoadingServiceImpl.java:390)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.doTransformation(AppClassLoader.java:382)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.transformClassBytes(AppClassLoader.java:375)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.transformClassBytes(AppClassLoader.java:360)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findClass(AppClassLoader.java:331)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findOrDelegateLoadClass(AppClassLoader.java:714)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.loadClass(AppClassLoader.java:586)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.loadClass(AppClassLoader.java:553)
...
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.enhance.EnhancingClassTransformerImpl.getEnhancer(EnhancingClassTransformerImpl.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.enhance.EnhancingClassTransformerImpl.transform(EnhancingClassTransformerImpl.java:49)
    at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAPUnitInfo.transformClass(JPAPUnitInfo.java:1263)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.ClassLoadingServiceImpl$ClassFileTransformerAdapter.transform(ClassLoadingServiceImpl.java:390)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.doTransformation(AppClassLoader.java:382)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.transformClassBytes(AppClassLoader.java:375)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.transformClassBytes(AppClassLoader.java:360)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findClass(AppClassLoader.java:331)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findOrDelegateLoadClass(AppClassLoader.java:714)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.loadClass(AppClassLoader.java:586)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.loadClass(AppClassLoader.java:553)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
```

My persistence unit configuration is the following:

```
<persistence xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <persistence-unit name="MY_DB" transaction-type="JTA">
        <description>MY Database</description>
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/APP/APP_db_hsql</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="PUBLIC" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="10000" />
            <property name="hibernate.order_inserts" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.order_updates" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.WebSphereLibertyJtaPlatform" />
            <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer" value="false"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And the configuration for the classloader is:

```
    <library
        apiTypeVisibility="spec,ibm-api,api,stable,third-party" id="libs">
        <fileset dir="${appl_path}/appl_libs" includes="*.jar"/>
    </library>

        <classloader
            apiTypeVisibility="spec,ibm-api,api,stable,third-party"
            commonLibraryRef="libs"     
        />
```

In the libs directory there are the following jars: hsqldb-2.4.1.jar, dom4j-1.6.1.jar and jandex-3.1.6.jar.

I'm using the following features:

```
        <featureManager>
            <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
            <feature>appSecurity-5.0</feature>
            <feature>beanValidation-3.0</feature>
            <feature>cdi-4.0</feature>
            <feature>enterpriseBeansLite-4.0</feature>
            <feature>mail-2.1</feature>
            <feature>restfulWS-3.1</feature>
            <feature>jdbc-4.2</feature>
            <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
            <feature>persistenceContainer-3.1</feature>
            <feature>faces-4.0</feature>
            <feature>pages-3.1</feature>
            <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
            <feature>servlet-6.0</feature>
            <feature>enterpriseBeansPersistentTimer-4.0</feature>
            <feature>xmlBinding-4.0</feature>
            <feature>xmlWS-4.0</feature>
            <feature>messagingClient-3.0</feature>
            <feature>ldapRegistry-3.0</feature>
            <feature>transportSecurity-1.0</feature>
            <feature>connectors-2.1</feature>
        </featureManager>
```

How can I resolve this error?

I tried downgrading the hibernate version or upgrading the liberty version, but this had the same errors. When I set delegation="parentLast" on the classloader, the error doesn't get thrown, but the persistenceManager can't be started.

Comment: The loop point seems to be in EnhancingClassTransformerImpl.getEnhancer():

Enhancer enhancer = Environment.getBytecodeProvider().getEnhancer( new EnhancementContextWrapper( enhancementContext, loader ) );

Possibly, one of the referenced classes is being transformed.

Comment: Can liberty trace with specification "com.ibm.ws.classloading.*=ALL" be collected?  That should show what classes are being loaded when the overflow occurs.

Comment: In this case, the transformer is one which was provided by JPA: com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAUnitInfo.  The problem symptom is consistent with transformation being performed on one of the classes related to this JPAUnitInfo transformer.